# How to print a live running console script output in a text field?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to make a tiny OS X app that would start a bash script on-demand and print its output in a text field, but not its result after its completion, **its result while it runs**.

It'll be just a simple app with one start/stop button.

Any ideas of how I could do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the answers on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406204/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-stdout-to-nstextview-in-cocoa) or just read documentation for classes [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSPipe](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Just edited my answer to make it a little more clear:

the idea is to add a notification (*NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification*) on the NSFileHandle returned by the NSPipe method *fileHandleForReading*.

Hope this helps =)