# Objective C print stdout to UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, stdout, nsfilehandle

I have a C function that prints to stdout using `fprintf`, and I'm attempting to display the contents of stdout in a `UIAlertView`.  My code is as follows:

```
NSFileHandle *stdoutFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput];
NSData *stdoutData = [stdoutFileHandle availableData];
NSString *stdoutString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stdoutData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

UIAlertView *stdoutAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"STDOUT OUTPUT" message:stdoutString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[stdoutAlert show];
```

I'm getting the following error when I run my code.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSFileHandleOperationException', reason: '[NSConcreteFileHandle availableData]: Bad file descriptor'**

I get an equivalent error when I replace `[stdoutFileHandle availableData]` with `[stdoutFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]`.

Comment: What you really need to do is something with `select` and a UNIX file descriptor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are reading from a output stream. To make this work you need to trick stdout to write it's contents to an input stream instead of to the console.

I know the old C way to do this, but you're not gonna like it. This uses [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pipe.html)() and [dup2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)().

```
int pipefd[2];

pipe(pipefd);
dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(pipefd[1]);
```

At this point anything written to stdout can be read by `pipefd[0]`. At that point you can use `-initWithFileDescriptor:` to read from `pipefd[0]`.

```
NSFileHandle *stdoutReader = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:pipefd[0]];
```

Note, you will want to do lots of error checking. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the selected answer post in this question:
[What is the best way to redirect stdout to NSTextView in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406204/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-stdout-to-nstextview-in-cocoa)

It felt a bit more familiar to follow for me. I created an NSPipe, and NSFileHandler object for the pipe and read handler and I used notifications. I put the open method below in the viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear method because of my needs but you can put it wherever it's appropriate

```
// Piping stdout info from here WILL NOT PIPE NSLOG:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406204/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-stdout-to-nstextview-in-cocoa
- (void) openConsolePipe {
    _pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    _pipeReadHandle = [_pipe fileHandleForReading] ;
    dup2([[_pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stdout)) ;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handleNotification:) name: NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification object: _pipeReadHandle] ;
    [_pipeReadHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify] ;
}

- (void) closeConsolePipe {
    if (_pipe != nil) {
        [[_pipe fileHandleForWriting] closeFile];

        // documentation suggests don't need to close reading file handle b/c auto but this suggests otherwise:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747232/using-nstask-and-nspipe-causes-100-cpu-usage
//        [[_pipe fileHandleForReading] closeFile];
    }
}

- (void) handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [_pipeReadHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify] ;
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: [[notification userInfo] objectForKey: NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // do what you want with the str here.
    [_consoleView setText:[_consoleView.text stringByAppendingString:str]];
    [_consoleView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([_consoleView.text length], 0)];
}
```

I hope this ends up helping someone else googling this...