# Cocoa App: Binding stdin/stdout to NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I have a C code which embeds Lua interpreter and some scripts. These scripts relies on stdin/stdout for user input/output.

I am trying to write a simple cocoa application with single NSTextField which will act as a stdin/stdout for my C code.

I was able to bind stdout as explained on this link:
[What is the best way to redirect stdout to NSTextView in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406204/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-stdout-to-nstextview-in-cocoa)

How do I bind stdin with my NSTextField?
( In simple word, "scanf" should be able to receive input from text field. )

NOTE: I don't want to use NSTask. My C code has to be part of my cocoa app. ( basically there is no sub-process )